# Countdown when is zero dont work very well

Tags: javascript, momentjs, countdown

I have a countdown in my web and work very well but when my countdown reaches zero it shows two values ​​at the same time. If I refresh webpage it fix. I dont understand why.

I use momentjs and countdownjs

[Show here](https://jsfiddle.net/vkmx1s04/) how it work

```js
function showCountdown(hasta) {

  moment.locale('es')
  var hora = moment()
  var first = moment('09:00', 'HH:mm')
  var second = moment('12:00', 'HH:mm')
  var third = moment('15:00', 'HH:mm')
  var fourth = moment('18:00', 'HH:mm')
  var fiveth = moment('21:00', 'HH:mm')
  var sixth = moment('23:59', 'HH:mm')

  switch (true) {
    case hora.isBefore(first):
      var hasta = first
      break;
    case hora.isBetween(first,second):
      var hasta = second
      break;
    case hora.isBetween(second,third):
      var hasta = third
      break;
    case hora.isBetween(third,fourth):
      var hasta = fourth
      break;
    case hora.isBetween(fourth,fiveth):
      var hasta = fiveth
      break;
    case hora.isBetween(fiveth,sixth):
      var hasta = sixth
      break;
    case hora.isAfter(sixth):
      var hasta = first.add(1,'d')
      break;
  }

  function f(n) { return n<10 ? '0'+n : n; }

  countdown(hasta, function(ts) {
      var countdownMatch = f(ts.hours||'0')+':'+f(ts.minutes)+':'+f(ts.seconds).toString();
      $('.countdownMatch').html(countdownMatch)
    }, countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);

}
setInterval(showCountdown, 1000);
```

SOLUTION:
I change setInterval(showCountdown, 1000) to showCountdown() and my JS files call aren't in a correct place (moment and countdown).

Comment: What two values is it showing?

Comment: The countdown blinking with two values. I think one regressive and other progressive when it reaches zero.

EDIT: [Here can see the problem](https://i.gyazo.com/db001b0e45534763f4cb6b33f5ae9e1a.mp4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing this by calling `setInterval`. You are spawning a new countdown every second, and those count downs are competing with eachother to update that html element.

Change it to simply call `showCountdown()` instead of with the set interval part.

Comment: I understand what you say, but I'm not sure what your solution is. Could you explain me?

Comment: @Kevinsillo change `setInterval(showCountdown, 1000);` to `showCountdown()`

Comment: I try but not worked for me... div show 00:00:00. In jsfiddle works but in my code no lol

Comment: The problems is in my js files... with CDN works fine. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can correct this problem with the use of `clearInterval()` as the Countdown.js [doc](http://countdownjs.org/readme.html) suggests:

```
var counter = countdown(hasta, function(ts) {  // <-- assign countdown to counter variable
    var countdownMatch = f(ts.hours||'0')+':'+f(ts.minutes)+':'+f(ts.seconds).toString();
      $('.countdownMatch').html(countdownMatch)
    }, countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS);

window.clearInterval(counter);  // <-- clear the countdown interval
```